# CFChart labels are offset

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfchart

I am trying to work with CFChart and am having an issue with the labels of the columns being about 3 inches to the right of the graph.

Here is a pic of it:

[image]

I have been trying to figure out how to get that correctly set over the column. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
            <cfchart format="png" type="bar" show3d="no" xoffset="YES" showlegend="false" chartHeight="200" chartWidth="180">
               <cfchartseries colorlist="##E18014,green,red" type="bar">
                     <cfchartdata item="Sent" value="10">
                     
                     <cfchartdata item="Delivered" value="8">
                     
                     <cfchartdata item="Failure" value="2">
                     
               </cfchartseries>
        </cfchart>
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code. What does the outer HTML container look like? Feels like s CSS issue. `CFChart` is just an implementation of https://www.zingchart.com/. Depending on which version of CF you're using, it may be easier to just implement the latest ZingChart code directly.

Comment: I added the code above.... We are using CF10. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Perhaps other code in the page is causing the issue? The issue doesn't happen when running the snippet on trycf.com https://trycf.com/gist/6ff01d0cc7148f74fe51b20f8c8256ca/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: It might be relavent that your code has `<cfchartdata item="Sent" value="10">` while your graph shows a value of 13.

Comment: The bad news is that you're using an ancient version of CF.  The good news is that there's an ancient blog post that just might solve your problem.  The bad news is that when you do eventually upgrade to a newer version of CF, you will have to remove this kludgey workaround if it actually does work work for you. https://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2009/3/6/Using-jQuery-to-fix-CFCHARTs-tooltip-behavior